# Report Builder does not do the calculations from the sql-query

Tags: sql, union, reportbuilder3.0, qsqlquery

I am making a report in Report Builder. I use a query that I developed in the Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio. In that query I need to duplicate one row of data(1), change the units (2) and multiply it by 5.6 (3)

```
select * from (

select * from base where (ANALYSIS != 'A' AND ANALYSIS != 'B')

union all

select
ANALYSIS,
NAME,
case
when UNITS = 'mmol/l' then '°Duits'
end as UNITS,
minimum * 5.6,
gemiddelde * 5.6,
maximum * 5.6,

from base
where ANALYSIS = 'COMPONENT'

) as addunion

order by ANALYSIS
```

[image]

This works perfectly in the Microsoft SQL Server Managment Studio, but when I trie to copy this query to Report Builder. It only changes units and does not multiply a value. DO you have any idea why this happens?

[image]

Comment: select ... UNION ALL ... select...

Comment: yes I had this just removed it by accident while posting it here. my apologies